# Algorithms for finding a Tutte-Berge maximizer

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, algorithms, matching-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph. The Tutte-Berge formula states that a maximum matching on $G$ has size $$\nu(G)=\frac12\left(|V|-\max_{U\subset V}(o(V-U)-|U|)\right)$$ with $o(V-U)$ the number of connected components of $V-U$ of odd size.

**Question:** How much is known about algorithms for finding $U\subset V$ maximizing $o(V-U)-|U|$? I am having trouble finding any resources about this question.

I did come up with a polynomial time algorithm by myself. I determined that you can construct such $U$ by iteratively finding a vertex $v\in V$ such that $\nu(V-\{v\})=\nu(V)-1$. This requires solving $O(|V|^2)$ maximum matching problems, and thus runs in polynomial time. However, I would like to know if there is any faster algorithm.

Comment: Did you mean to call $U$ a Tutte–Berge minimizer in your title? I assumed it's a typo and called it a "Tutte–Berge maximizer" in my answer, since after all it maximizes the deficiency $o(G-U) - |U|$.

Comment: Right, there are multiple ways of writing the Tutte-Berge formula, depending on which $U$ is either minimizing or maximizing a quantity. Anyways, I changed it to say maximizer in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to do $O(|V|^2)$ passes of a maximum matching algorithm; a single pass is enough if we're careful about it, use the right algorithm, and look at the additional data that algorithm generates.

Suppose you go looking for a maximum matching in $G$ using the [blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm). This takes us through some number of steps of finding augmenting paths and contracting odd cycles (blossoms). At the end of the algorithm, we find a maximum matching $M'$ in some smaller graph $G'$, and by expanding the blossoms again we can obtain a maximum matching $M$ in $G$. At this stage:

1. Right before expanding the blossoms, we can find a Tutte–Berge maximizer in $G'$;
2. After we expand the blossoms, it remains a Tutte–Berge maximizer in $G$.

### Finding a Tutte–Berge maximizer in $G'$

Here, the blossom algorithm has built a forest $F$ in $G'$ (called an *$M'$-alternating forest*) in which each tree component has a root in $S$: the set of vertices not covered by the matching. We say that a vertex is an *inner* vertex if its distance in $F$ from a root is odd, and an *outer* vertex if the distance is even. By the algorithm, all inner vertices have degree $2$ in $F$: they have one parent and one child, and the edge from each inner vertex to its child is an edge of $M'$.

This much should hold at every step of the blossom algorithm. When we've reached the end, we also know the following:

- No outer vertex has neighbors outside $F$; otherwise, we could use those neighbors to expand the forest.
- Two outer vertices cannot be adjacent. If there were an edge between two outer vertices in different components of $F$, we would find an $M'$-augmenting path; if there were an edge between two outer vertices in the same component of $F$, we would find a blossom.

In this case, let $U$ be the set of inner vertices: this set $U$ is a Tutte–Berge maximizer in $G'$! Why? Well, by the observations above, the outer vertices can only have neighbors in $U$, so in particular, they are odd components of $G' - U$. The number of outer vertices is exactly $|U| + |S|$, because each outer vertex in the forest $F$ is either a root or the unique child of an inner vertex. Therefore $o(G' - U) - |U|$ is exactly $|S|$, the number of vertices uncovered by a maximum matching in $G'$.

### Returning to $G$

We wanted to find a Tutte–Berge maximizer in $G$, not $G'$. To do this, we expand the blossoms, one at a time, and see what happens to $U$.

Each blossom is an odd cycle containing $k$ inner vertices and $k+1$ outer vertices of an alternating forest; after the blossom is contracted, it becomes a single outer vertex of an alternating forest in the smaller graph. Therefore, as we expand the blossoms, the set $U$ is left untouched: it started out consisting of inner vertices only, and as we expand, it continues to consist of inner vertices only (though it will no longer contain *all* the inner vertices).

Meanwhile, the odd components in the complement of $U$ will remain odd components. As we expand the blossoms, they might get bigger. However, they'll remain isolated from each other, and replacing a vertex by an odd cycle will not change their parity.

Therefore $o(G-U) - |U|$ in the original graph $G$ will have the same value as $o(G'-U) - |U|$ did in $G'$. The number of vertices uncovered by the maximum matching also remains the same: expanding a blossom of length $2k+1$ adds $2k$ vertices, but also adds $k$ edges to the matching. We conclude that $U$ is still a Tutte–Berge maximizer in $G$.

### A worse but lazier solution

If we stick to treating the blossom algorithm (or any alternative) as a black box, we can still do better and identify a Tutte–Berge maximizer after only solving $O(|V|)$ maximum matching problems.

Let $D$ be the set of all inessential vertices of $G$: the vertices that are left uncovered by some maximum matching in $G$. A vertex $v \in D$ can be identified by the property that $G-v$ and $G$ have maximum matchings of the same size. Next, split $V(G)-D$ into sets $A$ and $C$, defined to be the essential vertices adjacent to some vertex in $D$, and the other essential vertices.

The partition $A \cup C \cup D$ is the [Gallai–Edmonds decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallai%E2%80%93Edmonds_decomposition) of $G$. In particular, the set $A$ is a Tutte–Berge maximizer.

Comment: I just read something on wikipedia about factor-critical graphs that gives me an idea based on Gallai-Edmonds decomposition. On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor-critical_graph#Characterizations they give a quick method by breadth first search to check from a perfect matching whether the graph is factor-critical. Maybe the same method can be used to find the Gallai-Edmonds decomposition in linear time from a maximum matching? That would reduce finding a Tutte-Berge maximizer to finding a maximum matching.

Comment: In a sense, isn't that what the blossom algorithm is doing?

Comment: I'm gonna be honest, the blossom algorithm is still a little bit vague to me. Different sources explain it in different ways and end up with different running times. I think the wikipedia explanation in particular is very hard to follow with the stuff about building a forest. But if a Gallai-Edmonds decomposition can be found in linear time from a maximum matching, then you would also be able to use faster maximum matching algorithms than the blossom algorithm. Furthermore, if a maximum matching can be found in linear time from a Gallai-Edmonds decomposition this would prove equivalence.

Comment: A maximum matching can easily be found from the Gallai-Edmonds decomposition. I don't expect to be able to go the other way without building the whole blossom-algorithm forest first, which is quick but not easy.

Comment: Right, because finding all inessential vertices by breadth first search, you run into problems with odd cycles again, so you have to contract the blossoms again.

Comment: Lovász and Plummer's *Matching Theory* also has a matching algorithm (not difficult, but with many cases) specifically based on the Gallai-Edmonds decomposition. In particular, if you *start* from a maximum matching, it should find the G-E decomposition in $O(n \cdot |D|)$ time: it works by maintaining a list $\mathcal L$ of matchings and a set $D(\mathcal L)$ of vertices uncovered by one of those matchings, and if $D(\mathcal L)$ is not yet equal to the $D$ of the G-E decomposition, then in linear time it finds a new matching to add to $\mathcal L$ and increase $|D(\mathcal L)|$.